How can I make expressjs partition and download one after the other to the user since it weighs 40 gb as for example
How can I make expressjs partition and download one after the other to the user since it weighs 40 gb as for example
var splitFileStream = require("split-file-stream");
const { parse } = require("url");

app.get("/edocument/bloques/descargarArchivos", async (req, res) => {
 
    var nombreArchivoArreglo = [
      {"pedimento": "0192120004WM3.pdf","path": "D:/Iván Laguna/pruebas/1-dsk_D/Procesados"},
      {"pedimento": "0192120004Z91.pdf","path": "D:/Iván Laguna/pruebas/1-dsk_D/Procesados" },
      {"pedimento": "0192120007SF1.pdf","path": "D:/Iván Laguna/pruebas/1-dsk_D/Procesados" }
    ];
    
    const tamañoMaximo = 10 * 1024 * 1024;
    
    var customSplit = splitFileStream.getSplitWithGenFilePath(
      (n) => `./output.zip.${(n + 1).toString().padStart(3, '0')}`
    );
    
    var archive = archiver('zip', {
      gzip: true,
      zlib: { level: 9 } // Establece el nivel de compresión.
    });
    
    nombreArchivoArreglo.forEach((nombreArchivo) => {
      archive.file(nombreArchivo.path + "/" + nombreArchivo.pedimento, {
        name: nombreArchivo.pedimento,
      });
    });
    
    customSplit(archive, parseInt(tamañoMaximo), (error, filePaths) => {
      if (error) throw error;
      console.log("Este es un array de mis nuevos archivos:", filePaths);

      for (let i = 0; i < filePaths.length; i++){
        res.download(filePaths[i], `particion_ ${i +  1 }.zip`, (err) =>{
         if(err){
          throw err;
         } else{
          
         }
        })
      }
    
    });
    
    archive.on('error', function (err) {
      throw err;
    });
    
    archive.finalize();
});

